# Boxplot labels with the number of non-missing values in R

Tags: r, count, label, boxplot, counting

I have several columns (in a data frame) and boxplot them with this command:

`boxplot(allm, las=2)`

It´s all ok, but I wish to put in the label how many non-missing observations they are in each column (in this case the numeric values, because I have NAs too).

A data frame used to draw a boxplot looks like it:

```
NE001710    NE001360    NE001398    NE001380    NE001707
-0.12        -0.61       -0.61        -0.02       0.13
-0.58        -0.43       -0.24        -0.27      -0.47
  NA          0.19       -0.37        -0.14      -0.53
  NA         -0.13       -0.27        -0.38       0.05
  NA          NA          0.32        -0.34       0.01
```

The desired labels of the boxplot have to be something like `NE001710(2)`, `NE0011360(4)`... `NE001707(5)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `sprintf` function (or `paste` or some other one that would allow you to create a set of labels before a call to `boxplot`).

Exemplary data:

```
data <- data.frame(v1=runif(5), v2=runif(5), v3=runif(5))
data[1,1] <- NA
data[1,2] <- NA
data[2,1] <- NA
data
##          v1         v2        v3
## 1        NA         NA 0.3031038
## 2        NA 0.99395272 0.9481445
## 3 0.4596111 0.17398552 0.6135870
## 4 0.9175369 0.02094728 0.7256759
## 5 0.1932377 0.71577514 0.8811639
```

Generate labels with `sprintf` - combine the column names and the number of NAs into one string:

```
(nam <- sprintf("%s (%d)",
                   colnames(data),
                   apply(data, 2, function(d) sum(!is.na(d)))
))
## "v1 (3)" "v2 (4)" "v3 (5)"
```

Draw:

```
boxplot(data, names=nam)
```

Comment: Work´s perfetly, but my label is truncated (cut) now. can I do something?

Comment: Try substituting the first arg of `sprintf` with `"%s\n(%d)"`. Otherwise, draw a `horizontal=TRUE` boxplot and change plot margins e.g. to `par(mar=c(4,6,4,2))`.

Comment: Ops, now I realize that it counted the Na values. I wanna the contrary, the non NA values...

Comment: how can I get a `nam` just with the numbers (without the collumn name)

Comment: `nam <- as.character(apply(data, 2, function(d) sum(!is.na(d))))`

Answer (score 1):

You can change the names of your columns using the code below:

```
for(i in c(1:length(allm))){
colnames(allm)[i]<-paste(colnames(allm)[i],"(", sum(!is.na(allm[,i])),")", sep="")
}
```